# Base64 Encoding on ng-file-upload

Tags: ng-file-upload

When a file is selected or dropped, is it automatically converted to Base64 encoding?

I need to be able to take files, convert them to strings then pass them into POST requests to our backend.

Is ng-file-upload already converting the file? Or is this something I need to manually do by calling either the:

```
Upload.base64DataUrl(files).then(function(urls){...});
```

or

```
Upload.dataUrl(file, boolean).then(function(url){...});
```

methods?

I can post the relevant code but this seems relatively straightforward. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You should convert it manually if you want to convert it to base64 encoded string and those methods are correct.

Comment: Danial, thanks for the response. Do I include the conversion within the POST request? Or do I convert first then use the converted data within the body of the POST? I am not seeing a clear methodology for data conversion.

Comment: Depends on how your server expects it. There is also `Upload.http()` but it sends the file binary not base64. For example you can do `Upload.dataUrl(file).then((base64) => {$http.post(url, base64);})`